# Pyspark: adding dataframe values to each distinct value in a specified column

Tags: join, merge, pyspark, concatenation

I need to add dataframe values to each distinct value in a specified column

for example

df1:

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   A| 100|
|   B|  70|
|   C|  50|
+----+----+
```

df2:

```
+----+----+
|col3|col4|
+----+----+
|jose|   1|
|  li|   2|
| liz|   3|
+----+----+
```

The resulting df should look likes:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   A| 100|jose|   1|
|   B|  70|jose|   1|
|   C|  50|jose|   1|
|   A| 100|  li|   2|
|   B|  70|  li|   2|
|   C|  50|  li|   2|
|   A| 100| liz|   3|
|   B|  70| liz|   3|
|   C|  50| liz|   3|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for `crossJoin` actually -

```
df = df1.crossJoin(df2)
df.show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   A| 100|jose|   1|
|   A| 100|  li|   2|
|   A| 100| liz|   3|
|   B|  70|jose|   1|
|   B|  70|  li|   2|
|   B|  70| liz|   3|
|   C|  50|jose|   1|
|   C|  50|  li|   2|
|   C|  50| liz|   3|
+----+----+----+----+
```